# approximating a geometric sum of exponentials by an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $e(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$. Let $I = [a,b]$ be a closed interval of real numbers.
I am interested in the sum
$$
S = \sum_{n \in I \cap \mathbb{Z}} e(\alpha n)
$$ 
for some real number $\alpha.$ Do there exists constants $c_1, c_2>0$ such that we can approximate 
$S$ by integral, 
$$
c_2 |\int_I  e(\alpha x) dx| \leq |S| \leq c_1 |\int_I  e(\alpha x) dx| ?
$$
The constants are independent of $I$ and $\alpha$. 
Do such constants exist? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such constants independent of $I$ and $\alpha$. For every $\alpha \neq 0$ we have
$$\int_I e(\alpha x)\,dx = 0$$
whenever the length of $I$ is an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{\lvert\alpha\rvert}$, and not for all such intervals does the sum vanish too: By moving the interval left or right one can pick up or drop one term of the sum [if the length of the interval is an integer, this depends on the interval not being half-open], and since $e(x)$ never vanishes, at most one of the two intervals can lead to a zero sum.

Thus for every fixed $c$ the inequality
$$\lvert S\rvert \leqslant c \biggl\lvert \int_I e(\alpha x)\,dx \biggr\rvert$$
is violated for infinitely many $I$ and $\alpha$.

Conversely, if $\alpha$ is not an integer, then $\lvert S\rvert$ can be made arbitrarily small while keeping the modulus of the integral above a fixed positive threshold: For a given run of integers $k \leqslant n \leqslant m$, you can choose $a$ freely in $(k-1,k]$ (and/or $b$ freely in $[m,m+1)$) without changing the sum, while the value of the integral varies. With
$$K := \sup_{y \in [0,1)}\; \biggl\lvert \int_0^y e(\alpha x)\,dx\biggr\rvert$$
one can always choose the interval such that
$$\biggl\lvert \int_I e(\alpha x)\,dx \biggr\rvert \geqslant \frac{K}{2}\,.$$
Hence for every fixed $c > 0$ also the inequality
$$\lvert S\rvert \geqslant c \biggl\lvert \int_I e(\alpha x)\,dx \biggr\rvert$$
is violated for infinitely many $I$ and $\alpha$.